# Why does this avi file with raw video yield only one frame=

Tags: ffmpeg, binary, file-format, avi

I created an [AVI file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a245i5xz0wu66bf/stroke.avi.tar.gz?dl=0) by rendering the frames using Cairo. The AVI generation code is [part of an OCaml library](https://github.com/savonet/ocaml-mm/blob/master/src/video.ml#L138). However, ffmpeg and vlc both yield only the very first frame. If I cut the avi header and use ffplay with the proper codec options, I can view the movie just fine.

What causes ffmpeg to think this file has only one frame?

The header of the file looks like this:

```
0000000 4952 4646 d0e0 0278 5641 2049 494c 5453
0000010 00c0 0000 6468 6c72 7661 6869 0038 0000
0000020 a2c2 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000
0000030 003c 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000
0000040 01e0 0000 01e0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000050 0000 0000 0000 0000 494c 5453 0074 0000
0000060 7473 6c72 7473 6872 0038 0000 6976 7364
0000070 4752 2042 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000080 000a 0000 00f0 0000 0000 0000 003c 0000
0000090 2000 00fd 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000
00000a0 01e0 01e0 7473 6672 0028 0000 0028 0000
00000b0 01e0 0000 01e0 0000 0001 0018 0000 0000
00000c0 8c00 000a 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
00000d0 0000 0000 494c 5453 d00c 0278 6f6d 6976
00000e0 3030 6364 d000 0278 0000 0000 0000 0000
00000f0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. Something not mentioned in the docs I read was that the stream itself needs to be encoded as a list of CHUNKS. **So every frame shall be one CHUNK.** This is, of course, not necessary in principle, but seems to be a very common convention.